# Probablity that at least n selections from one sample exist in another

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-distribution

Have a probability question I'm not sure how to solve. Hopefully this makes sense:

1) Lets say we have a population of 1000 unique books.

2) First, we take a random sample (without replacement) of **500** of those 1000 books. Lets call this **S1**.

3) Second, we take another random sample (without replacement) of **750** of those same 1000 books. Lets call this **S2**.

What is the probability that >=100 books from S2 exist in S1?

What is the probability that <=100 books from S2 exist in S1?

What is the probability that exactly 100 books from S2 exist in S1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of the number of items in both samples is the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  Suppose we let $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$ denote the two samples from your initial population of $N=1000$ items, and let the operation $| \cdot |$ denote the size of a set.  Since the samples were formed independently via [simple random sampling without replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample) with $|\mathcal{S}_1| = 500$ and $|\mathcal{S}_2| = 750$ you have:

$$\mathbb{P}(|\mathcal{S}_1 \cap \mathcal{S}_2| = s) = \frac{{750 \choose s}{250 \choose 500-s}}{{1000 \choose 500}} \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } 250 \leqslant s \leqslant 500.$$

(Note that there must be *at least* $250$ items in both samples.)  So, you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(|\mathcal{S}_1 \cap \mathcal{S}_2| \geqslant 100) &= 1, \\[6pt]\mathbb{P}(|\mathcal{S}_1 \cap \mathcal{S}_2| \leqslant 100) &= 0, \\[6pt]
\mathbb{P}(|\mathcal{S}_1 \cap \mathcal{S}_2| = 100) &= 0. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll try and process this in my head :)

Comment: I think when I tried to scale my real data down to a test example (like the one here), I didn't think through it enough. I was expecting a probability different than simply 1 or 0. If S1 and S2 stayed the same, but the original N was changed to 20,000 vs 1000, I think it would give an answer more in the realm of what I was looking for. Will try and use the formula here and plug in the new numbers. Thanks again!